# How to find average of metrics between two dates in prometheus

Tags: average, prometheus, promql

Suppose I have a metric called speed, I want to find average of that metrics for date1 - date2

I tried to use function: avg_over_time(speed)[600s]

But the problem here is this will give the result of previous 10 minutes

I want average of data between custom dates
lets say today is 24-03-2022
I want data between 01-03-2022 and 05-03-2022

So how to do that, is there any other way, other than avg_over_time function?

Answer (score 1):

The `avg_over_time(speed[d])` returns the average value for the `speed` over the previous duration `d`. For example, `avg_over_time(speed[4d])` returns the average speed over the last 4 days. See [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-durations) for the accepted duration values.

Prometheus provides an [/api/v1/query](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#instant-queries) endpoint, which can be used for performing a query at a specific `time`. For example, the following command should return the average speed between `01-03-2022` and `05-03-2022` (excluding `05-03-2022`):

```sh
curl -G http://prometheus-host:9090/api/v1/query -d 'query=avg_over_time(speed[4d])' -d 'time=2022-03-05T00:00:00Z'
```

This also can be done when querying [/api/v1/query_range](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#range-queries) in Grafana with [`@` modifier](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#modifier):

```
avg_over_time(speed[4d] @ 1646431200)
```

Where `1646431200` is [Unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) for `05-03-2202` date.